# access the encrypted table in qgis

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I have a vector layer in qgis connected to PostgreSQL database table.

Suppose I encrypt the table column using pgp_sysm_encrypt or some other encryption in PostgreSQL

Is there any way i can say qgis to decrypt every column using my key